# Android device pingable but ADB shows offline

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb, android-things

I'm running Android Things on a Raspberry Pi 3 which has been working well with ADB over WiFi and everything. Just recently I've encountered an issue where ADB initially can't connect to the device, but shows the device as connected [offline].

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>adb connect 192.168.1.111
failed to connect to 192.168.1.111:5555
```

Then when I'm running `adb connect` again, I'm getting

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>adb connect 192.168.1.111
already connected to 192.168.1.111:5555
```

The device list in ADB shows

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>adb devices
List of devices attached
TA3640525I      device
192.168.1.5:5555        offline
```

Android Studio also treats the device as offline. 
Pinging works as;

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.1.5

Pinging 192.168.1.5 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.5: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.5: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.5: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.5: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
```

Restarting the ADB daemon does not work either

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>adb kill-server
```

I've not encountered this before, and it appeared all suddenly without any changes made to the system. I've tried to re-install ADB (ensuring that the SDK tools get removed), Android Studio and even device drivers. Any idea on what might have caused this?

Edit: I'm running Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise Version 10.0.16299 Build 16299

Edit: Other computers on the network work very well without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered that the device IP may have changed? The IP may be in use by another device that did not have adb.

Comment: I have verified the IP-address both in the Android Things GUI and in the router's admin panel.

Comment: Note that you are connected to 192.168.1.5 although your initial command is to connect to 192.168.1.111. Have you tried using Android.local as the address?

Comment: Good catch. The difference in IP was due to a change of network inbetween the tests, but both xxx.5 and xxx.111 pointed to the same physical device on each run. Same problem with Android.local though.